# numpy.where() with a 2d array and a 1d array in the condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

Given the following 2d numpy array:

```
>>> a = np.arange(4,10).reshape(2,3)
array([[4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

we can use `np.where()` to get indices of entries satisfying certain conditions.

```
>>> np.where(a == [4, 5, 6])
(array([0, 0, 0]), array([0, 1, 2]))
```

So far so good: the first array to be returned is the row idx's of where integers `4`,`5`,`6` appear in `a`, and the second array is the col idx's of where 4,5,6 appear in `a`.

```
>>> np.where(a == [4,5,8])
(array([0, 0]), array([0, 1]))
```

Why does the integer `8` not get picked up?

```
>>> np.where(a == [6,8,9])       
(array([1, 1]), array([1, 2]))
```

Why does the integer `6` not get picked up?

```
>>> np.where(a == [4,8,9])
(array([0, 1, 1]), array([0, 1, 2]))
```

How come the integer `4` **does** get picked up?

Comment: This isn't really to do with `where` - look at what e.g. `a == [4, 8, 9]` is giving you.

Comment: And if you don't know *why* that's what you're getting, note that `numpy` will compare the list to each row in the array; `8` isn't in the last place of any row, and `6` isn't in the first place (but `4` is).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to jonrsharpe's comments below my question, I was able to understand what was happening.

```
>>> > a = np.arange(5,10)
>>> a == [4,8,9]
array([[True, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

takes `[4,8,9]` and evaluates, for each 3-array entry of `a`, element by element, whether they are equal.

```
>>> np.where(a == [4,8,9])
(array([0, 1, 1]), array([0, 1, 2]))
```

gives the row and col indices of where `True` appears.

Comment: I think `np.transpose(np.where(a == [4,8,9]))` yields the row and col indices in a more readable fashion